# SQL query to grab most current record with multiple groupings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014 and Management Studio. Let me try to explain what I am doing.

I have a table which look similar to the following (very simplified)

[image]

I want to create a query which will grab the most current record for each parameter if the Well Global ID is the same.  What I want would look like the following:

[image]

With me not being a great SQL jockey I would like a little help.

The closest thing I could find was the following which doesn't take into account the parameter field so it would just grab the most current record if the Global ID matches:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    [OBJECTID], SampleDate, 
    Collector, Parameter, Result, Unit,
    WellGlobalID, GlobalID
FROM 
    WellSamples
WHERE 
    SampleDate IN (SELECT MAX(SampleDate) 
                   FROM WellSamples 
                   GROUP BY WellGlobalID);
```

Comment: either row_number() or rank() (depending on whether there can be multiple) and partition by parameter/globalid order by sample date desc. e.g. `select top 1000 * from (select *, row_number() over (partition by parameter, wellglobalid order by sampledate desc) rn from wellsamples) t where rn = 1;` There's like hundreds of other questions that ask this exact same question, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER` function.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT w.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parameter,wellglobalid 
                        ORDER BY sampledate DESC) as RN
    FROM WellSamples w
  ) x
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Awesome sauce,  just tried it and it worked!  Thank you so much.  You saved me some time.

Answer (score 1):

ROW_NUMBER would be my solution https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

```
SELECT
    [OBJECTID]
    ,SampleDate
    ,Collector
    ,Parameter
    ,Result
    ,Unit
    ,WellGlobalID
    ,GlobalID
FROM (  
    SELECT
        [OBJECTID]
        ,SampleDate
        ,Collector
        ,Parameter
        ,Result
        ,Unit
        ,WellGlobalID
        ,GlobalID
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Parameter, WellGlobalID ORDER BY     SampleDate DESC) AS [ROW_NUM]
    FROM WellSamples
    ) tbl
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

You need to subquery since windowed functions (ROW_NUMBER) can't be used in a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with a sub-query. First find the most recent date for each parameter and then join the rest of the data, like this:

```
SELECT w.parameter, w.sampledate, w.result, w.wellglobalid
FROM wellsamples w
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(sampledate) AS mxdate, parameter
 FROM wellsamples
 GROUP BY parameter) sub
ON w.parameter = sub.parameter
AND w.sampledate = sub.mxdate
```